# Rotating the screen on Android spams saved instance state and ActivityResultRegistry

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My app was saving a bigger bundle in activity onSaveInstanceState() each time the screen was rotated, and I came across something really confusing. Here is a minimal example:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

        val rcs = outState.getIntegerArrayList("KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_RCS")
        val keys = outState.getStringArrayList("KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_KEYS")

        Log.d("MainActivity", "${rcs?.size}: $rcs, $keys")
    }
}
```

I get the following output each time the screen is rotated:

```
3: [1332505437, 1835553837, 670316111], [FragmentManager:StartIntentSenderForResult, ...
6: [1332505437, 91080073, 1835553837, 381123153, 1187376284, 670316111], ...
...
```

See the full log after 6 rotations: https://pastebin.com/yfE04Fmc

Each time the screen is rotated, 3 elements are added to these two entries. After rotating the screen for a while, the instance state becomes significantly bigger for no apparent reason.

Target API: 30

Tested on: API 28 and 30

Does anyone know why this is happening?

**UPDATE**: I want to clarify that I do not save **any** state into the Bundle. The values I show are created by Android itself: in ActivityResultRegistry. I've created an empty project for this example, and the code I provided is the only code I have - there is nothing else that interacts with the state Bundle.

**UPDATE 2**: Bug report submitted: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191893160

**UPDATE 3**: Bug fixed, will be a part of `Activity 1.3.0-rc02` and `1.2.4` releases

Comment: It depends on how did you save the data into the `Bundle`. Did you adding or overwriting the data?

Comment: The minimal code in my example is all the code that you need to reproduce the issue. I don't save any data into the Bundle, but its size increases on every screen rotation.

Comment: What happen if you call `finish()` in `onDestroy()`? Please show your log output a little bit longer (multi lines).

Comment: @Darkman `finish()` in `onDestroy()` exits the app on rotation. here's the pastebin with the output after 6 screen rotations: https://pastebin.com/yfE04Fmc

Comment: Here's a very [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67540003/transactiontoolargeexception-on-viewpager2). Try to use a very basic layout e.g. `LinearLayout` without any contents and instead of extends `AppCompatActivity`; extends `Activity`.

Comment: @Darkman Using `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity` does help... I can't do that in a real project though, as I need to support older APIs. Is it a bug in the support library then?

Comment: ***"Is it a bug in the support library then?"*** Well, maybe. It seems so to me.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know why this is happening?

`AppCompatActivity` is extended from `ComponentActivity` (`AppCompatActivity -> FragmentActivity -> ComponentActivity`)

`ComponentActivity` is responsible for keeping the reference of `ViewModelFactory`, so that when the `Activity` recreates if can instantiate the same `ViewModel` before screen rotation.

Now inside `ComponentActivity` you will notice this:

```
@CallSuper
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    Lifecycle lifecycle = getLifecycle();
    if (lifecycle instanceof LifecycleRegistry) {
        ((LifecycleRegistry) lifecycle).setCurrentState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mSavedStateRegistryController.performSave(outState);
    mActivityResultRegistry.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Here the important part is `mActivityResultRegistry.onSaveInstanceState(outState)`

Inside this method you will see

```
public final void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    outState.putIntegerArrayList(KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_RCS,
            new ArrayList<>(mRcToKey.keySet()));
    outState.putStringArrayList(KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_KEYS,
            new ArrayList<>(mRcToKey.values()));
    outState.putStringArrayList(KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_KEYS,
            new ArrayList<>(mLaunchedKeys));
    outState.putBundle(KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_PENDING_RESULTS,
            (Bundle) mPendingResults.clone());
    outState.putSerializable(KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_RANDOM_OBJECT, mRandom);
}
```

So you can see from there that the Android platform itself is saving this key in the bundle. Hence you can not do much about it.

In other word, One of the parents of `AppCompatActivity` is saving these keys inside the `Bundle`. If you are not using `ViewModel` and do not want these keys to be saved; you can remove `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)` from `MainActivity` (**NOT RECOMMENDED**). You will still get your saved keys but there could be some side effect, I am not aware of.

Good thing that you have reported an issue regarding this, let's see how the Google Team respond to it.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you store the data in Bundle, according to standard Android developer document https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#restore-activity-ui-state-using-saved-instance-state

**Saving the state:**

```
 override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    outState?.run {
        putInt(STATE_SCORE, currentScore)
        putInt(STATE_LEVEL, currentLevel)
    }
    
    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }
    
    companion object {
       val STATE_SCORE = "playerScore"
       val STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel"
    }
```

**Restoring the state:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) // Always call the superclass first

// Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    with(savedInstanceState) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        currentScore = getInt(STATE_SCORE)
        currentLevel = getInt(STATE_LEVEL)
    }
} else {
    // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
}
// ...
}
```

Am not sure why you are getting the data from the bundle in onSaveInstanceState() method.

Also since you are saving list, want to highlight this point.

> Saved instance state bundles persist through both configuration
> changes and process death but are limited by storage and speed,
> because onSavedInstanceState() serializes data to disk. Serialization
> can consume a lot of memory if the objects being serialized are
> complicated. Because this process happens on the main thread during a
> configuration change, long-running serialization can cause dropped
> frames and visual stutter.
>
> Do not use store onSavedInstanceState() to store large amounts of
> data, such as bitmaps, nor complex data structures that require
> lengthy serialization or deserialization. Instead, store only
> primitive types and simple, small objects such as String. As such, use
> onSaveInstanceState() to store a minimal amount of data necessary,
> such as an ID, to re-create the data necessary to restore the UI back
> to its previous state should the other persistence mechanisms fail.
> Most apps should implement onSaveInstanceState() to handle
> system-initiated process death

Comment: Maybe I poorly phrased the issue. The minimal code in my example is all the code that you need to reproduce the issue. I don't save any data into the Bundle, but its size increases on every screen rotation. I've overridden the onsavedinstancestate function to debug and display the issue I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why u don't use ViewModel instead?

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve your problem but one thing that you could try is removing the duplicate values. Keep the latest ones and remove the olders. Something like this:

***Kotlin***

```kotlin
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    removeDuplicates(outState)
}

private fun removeDuplicates(bundle: Bundle) {
    val prevRCS = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("PREVIOUS_KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_RCS")
    val newRCS = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_RCS")
    val newKeys = bundle.getStringArrayList("KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_KEYS")
    if (newRCS == null || newKeys == null) return
    if (prevRCS == null) {
      
  bundle.putIntegerArrayList("PREVIOUS_KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_RCS", newRCS)
      
  //bundle.putStringArrayList("PREVIOUS_KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_KEYS", newKeys)
    } else if(prevRCS.size() != newRCS.size()) {
        for (rcs in prevRCS) {
            val index = newRCS.indexOf(rcs)
            newRCS.remove(index)
            newKeys.remove(index)
    }
    bundle.remove("KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_RCS")
    bundle.remove("KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_KEYS")
 
   bundle.putIntegerArrayList("KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_RCS", newRCS)
 
   bundle.putIntegerArrayList("PREVIOUS_KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_RCS", newRCS)
 
   bundle.putStringArrayList("KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_KEYS", newKeys)
 
   //bundle.putStringArrayList("PREVIOUS_KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_KEYS", newKeys)
    }
}
```

***Java***

```java
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    removeDuplicates(outState);
}

private static final void removeDuplicates(final Bundle bundle)
{
    if(bundle == null) return;

    final ArrayList<Integer> prevRCS = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("PREVIOUS_KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_RCS");
    final ArrayList<Integer> newRCS = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_RCS");
    final ArrayList<String> newKeys = bundle.getStringArrayList("KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_KEYS");

    if(newRCS == null || newKeys == null) return;

    if(prevRCS == null) {
 
   bundle.putIntegerArrayList("PREVIOUS_KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_RCS", newRCS);
 
   //bundle.putStringArrayList("PREVIOUS_KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_KEYS", newKeys);
    } else if(prevRCS.size() != newRCS.size()) {
        for(Integer rcs : prevRCS) {
            final int index = newRCS.indexOf(rcs);
            newRCS.remove(index);
            newKeys.remove(index);
        }
    bundle.remove("KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_RCS");
    bundle.remove("KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_KEYS");
 
   bundle.putIntegerArrayList("KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_RCS", newRCS);
 
   bundle.putIntegerArrayList("PREVIOUS_KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_RCS", newRCS);
   bundle.putStringArrayList("KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_KEYS", newKeys);
 
   //bundle.putStringArrayList("PREVIOUS_KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_KEYS", newKeys);
    }
}
```

Comment: But can we be sure that these keys can be removed safely?

Comment: You can just test it on any device I think. If it works, it should be consistent across other devices. Why? Well because it should be confined/enclosed in that support library only.

Comment: Right, but library updates may unexpectedly break this, correct? I should probably file a bug report instead

Comment: I thought you've already done that. No it wont break the future code; that's why it checks for the sizes between the previous and the newest values in the `else if`. If the keys don't exist, it will return immediately.

Comment: yes, I see that you are removing only the old values. but what guarantees do we have that (1) these values are not used by something now and (2) these values will not be used in the future. I think the argument that it just works without them is not ideal